# e.preventDefault(); not stopping form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple form validation script, that just checks fields aren't empty to begin with (further advanced validation will be added later).

However, on submission, the form seems to continue to submit, even though I am using `preventDefault()`. Could someone check my syntax and my logic for me please, figure out what's going wrong? I get a flash of the validation before the form submits as normal.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qb9KS/1/

**HTML**

```
<form id="userForm" method="POST" action="form-process.php">
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>User Information</legend>

            <div id="errorDiv"></div>

            <label for="name">Name:*</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
            <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="nameError">Name is required</span>

            <br />

            <label for="city">City:</label>
            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" />

            <br />

            <label for="state">State:</label>
            <select id="state" name="state">
                <option></option>
                <option>Alabama</option>
                <option>California</option>
                <option>Colorado</option>
                <option>Florida</option>
                <option>Illinois</option>
                <option>New Jersey</option>
                <option>New York</option>
                <option>Wisconsin</option>
            </select>

            <br />

            <label for="zip">ZIP:</label>
            <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" />

            <br />

            <label foe="email">Email Address:*</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
            <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="emailError">Email is required</span>

            <br />

            <label for="phone">Telephone Number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
            <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="phoneError">Format: xxx-xxx-xxxx</span>

            <br />

            <label for="work">Number Type:</label>
            <input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="phoneType" id="work" value="work" />
            <label class="radioButton" for="work">Work</label>
            <input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="phoneType" id="home" value="home" />
            <label class="radioButton" for="home">Home</label>
            <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="phonetypeError">Please choose an option</span>

            <br />

            <label for="password1">Password:*</label>
            <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1" />
            <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="password1Error">Password required</span>

            <br />

            <label for="password2">Verify Password:*</label>
            <input type="password" id="password2" name="password2" />
            <span class="errorFeedback errorSpan" id="password2Error">Passwords don't match</span>

            <br />

            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#userForm").submit(function(e) {
    removeFeedback();
    var errors = validateForm();
    if (errors == "") {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        provideFeedback(errors);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});

function validateForm() {
    var errorFields = new Array();
    if ($('#name').val() == "") {
        errorFields.push('name');
    }
    if ($('#email').val() == "") {
        errorFields.push('email');
    }
    if ($('#password1').val() == "") {
        errorFields.push('password1');
    }
    return errorFields;
}

function provideFeedback(incomingErrors) {
    for (var i = 0; i < incomingErrors.length; i++) {
        $("#" + incomingErrors[i]).addClass("errorClass");
        $("#" + incomingErrors[i] + "Error").removeclass("errorFeedback");
    }
    $("#errorDiv").html("Errors encountered");
}

function removeFeedback() {
    $("#errorDiv").html("");
    $('input').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("errorClass");
    });
    $('.errorSpan').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass("errorFeedback");
    });
}
});
```

Comment: first off, since you are returning false anyways, you dont need to prevent the default as well.  `return false` will prevent the form submission by itself

Comment: `validateForm` returns an array, which you then check against a string...

Comment: you only prevent default in one case of `if`, in first case you return `true` so form will submit using browser default method. What are you expecting

Comment: I want the form to submit if the fields have values. If they don't, it should halt and the validation shows the errors.

Comment: Fiddleized this question [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DDkXQ/)

Comment: @Cameron (and whoever upvoted the comment) - type coercion, it makes wonders in JS. Yes, it's easier just to check `errors.length` instead, but in this case the code works exactly as planned.

Comment: Forked and added CSS styling so you can see what should happen. http://jsfiddle.net/qb9KS/1/, thanks.

Comment: @raina77ow It's not good Javascript practice to abuse type coercion like that. If you don't expect a string, you shouldn't compare to a string. In this case, he only wants to pass if he's got no errors, i.e. `errors.length` so he should explicitly check for this case. When you magically compare different types you can confuse others who are working on the project and you can cause errors that could have otherwise been avoided had you performed the proper check in the first place.

Comment: @izuriel And I agree to this completely. ) While this check wasn't the source of a problem, 5 people thought it might be - so obviously it better be rephrased. But didn't I mention this in my comment? )

Comment: @raina77ow Apologies then I must have misinterpreted your stance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be...

```
$("#" + incomingErrors[i] + "Error").removeClass("errorFeedback");
```

... instead. As jQuery object doesn't have `removeclass` method (and case does matter in JS), this function fails with an error, and neither `e.preventDefault()` nor `return false` lines are invoked.

The bottom line: always check JS console for errors, it'll save you A LOT of time and nerves. )

Comment: Thank you. A simple typo, as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `array.length` instead of `=`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#userForm").submit(function(e) {

      if (errors.length >0) {
            return true;
       }
    }

}
```

you also typo error in `removeClass`

```
$("#" + incomingErrors[i] + "Error").removeClass("errorFeedback");
```

Comment: -1 He wants to prevent submitting only in case of errors, not always. Anyway that's not the point of his error.

Comment: I've removed my downvote but this still doesn't supply a solution for the problem.

Comment: How exactly does this advice solve the problem? Who the hell upvoted this?